# install ZeosLib on xe5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

i found this project for connecting to mysql servers!
 : http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/

but for installing on XE5 i got the flowing error :

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] ZCore.dpk(56): F1026 File not found: 'C:\Users\peiman\Desktop\rad\mysql\packages\DelphiXE5\ZFastCode.dcu'
```

i searched the file for `ZFastCode.dcu` but there isnt any file with this name in all parts of the projects

any body know how can i fix this!?

Comment: OT: don't you have FireDAC as part of your Delphi ?

Comment: why my xe5 havnt firedac ? i must buy it?

Comment: From a quick view, it should be part of Delphi XE5 Professional, where there is a limitation for localhost only connections. The higher SKUs has no such limit. And finally, Starter edition has no FireDAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just Remove line for ZFastCode.pas from your ZCore package file.